FastReport .NET How to call (Invalidate) (re-render) for preview?
I have FastReport Community
Code:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using FastReport;
using FastReport.Data;
using FastReport.Dialog;
using FastReport.Barcode;
using FastReport.Table;
using FastReport.Utils;

namespace FastReport
{
  public class ReportScript
  {
      private void Text2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        var obj = sender as TextObject;
        if (obj != null)
        {
          // Change the font size of the TextObject
          obj.Font = new Font(obj.Font.FontFamily, 15);
        }
      }
   }
}

In preview: When I clicked on text2 nothing changed. But if I click and then doing scroll or resize all changed.
How I can call re-render for this element?
enter image description here
